# Python converting sec to min with while and if

Tags: python, time

```
minutes = 0
def sec_to_min():
    seconds = int(input("How many seconds you want to convert?"))
    while True:
        if seconds >= 60:
            seconds =-60
            minutes =+1
            print(minutes)
            return True
        else:
            print(seconds,"sec")
            return False

sec_to_min()
```

When I input 60 or more, it will print just "1", nothing more. My **if** is not working.  I tried to move "seconds" in front of function but it gave me an error, something like "local variable 'seconds' referenced before assignment"

Comment: Did you mean to write `seconds -= 60` (decrement seconds by sixty) instead of `seconds = -60` (setting seconds to negative sixty)? Same for minutes (that's why it only returns 1; you only ever set it to 1).

Comment: Please format your code properly. The problem is that you `return` from the function in both `if` and `else` statements. And do you have to do that with the loop.

Comment: thank you guys for advice, but i dont really know what do you think here, can you update my code please?

Comment: The first comment has told you exactly what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @MatejPakán is quite correct; fixing the code is *your* job.  Others found and described the problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, i am pretty new at this site, this is my first problem... anyway, i solve this problem with your help, thank you guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll summarize:

We think you've confused two types of statements:

```
seconds = -60
seconds -= 60
```

The first one deletes the previous value of **seconds** and assigns a new value of **-60**; the second is equivalent to

```
seconds = seconds - 60
```

The flow of your code suggests that this second one is what you need; the same change applies to **minutes**.

You have a conflict in your **while** logic: although the loop control seems to want to repeat the loop for a while, it gets interrupted during the first iteration by one **return** statement or the other.  You have no way to reach the bottom of the loop and go back for a second iteration.

Why are you returning a Boolean value?  That's not clear, since your main code doesn't use it.  If you do require the return value, perhaps you need to set a variable within the loop, and then return that variable *after* the loop.

Comment: yes, that helped me a lot, also i needed to remove `return True`

Comment: Also remember to up-vote things you found helpful, such as the seminal comments you got right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
def sec_to_min():
    minutes=0
    seconds = int(input("How many seconds you want to convert?"))  
    while True:    
        if seconds>=60:
            while seconds>=60:
                seconds =seconds-60
                minutes+=1
            print(minutes)
            break
        else:
            print(seconds,"sec")
            break
sec_to_min()
```

the problem was that you run the if only one time + the symbols were all upside down